# Find the interior and closure of a subset on $R^2$

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{R^2}$ with the usual topology and $M=\{(x,0) : x\in \mathbb{R} \}$ find $\overline{M}, M^o$

---

my first thought was that $M$ is open, but it's wrong because it does exist such neighborhood in $\mathbb{R^2}$ such that for every $x\in M$,  $S(x,r) \subseteq M$.
I believe its closed since $\mathbb{R^2}\setminus M$ is the set $\{(x,y):x\in  \mathbb{R}, y\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\} \}$ which is an open set.

So because  $S(x,r)\nsubseteq M \Rightarrow$ $M^o= \emptyset$ and since $M$ is closed $\overline{M}=M$

**is this correct?**

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Any line has no interior and it's closed.